# How to get all keys that include dash?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to workaround a [deficiency in `yargs` library](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/1679#issuecomment-1142336456) where types for configuration are produced both as kamelCase and kebab-case, e.g.

```
const argv = yargs
  .env('CAS')
  .help()
  .options({
    'app-path': {
      demand: true,
      type: 'string',
    },
  })
  .parseSync();

export type Configuration = typeof argv;
```

Now `Configuration` is `{'app-path': string, appPath: string}`.

I want to Omit dash-containing keys. However, how do I Pick all keys that contain a dash in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to the rescue:

```
type A = { 'app-path': string, appPath: string }

type B = Omit<A, `${string}-${string}`>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDkBDMYC0Z3AAtUAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMAaKTMABXwNIpoagF8AUINCQoAIQRQA8gFtqwADwxmAAwAkSHnXr9sm7Q36qA3IID05qNYB6AfiA)

Comment: This seems like the correct answer. However, in the context of yargs, for some reason using `Omit` with any value removes all properties. Odd.

Comment: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/1679#issuecomment-1142386444

Comment: The docs for template literal types and for Omit do not seem to show examples that are anything like this. Would you happen to know where this sort of usage is explained? Or perhaps add a bit more explanation yourself?

Comment: @MikeM I'm insufferably curious. I don't have a reference, unfortunately. I figured this stuff out when I last had a decent play with template literal types: https://tsplay.dev/mq54Qm

Comment: @MikeM I'll off now, but if I get bored later, I'll have a look at the yargs types and try to move this forward

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the keys of the `Configuration` object and use a filter.

```
const keysToOmit = Object.keys(configObject).filter(s => Boolean(s.match(/-/)))

// keysToOmit: ['app-path']
```

Then you can iterate through the keys and omit them from the object.

```
keysToOmit.forEach(key => delete configObject[key])

// configObject: {appPath: 'string'}
```

Probably it's also wise to first clone the object before modifying it. Especially if you expect objects to be treated as immutable in your application.

Comment: I believe that this is a type-based question, not about the JS mechanics of filtering props from an object.

Comment: @spender is correct.

Comment: Fair enough. I see you've already answered how to define the type as well.